# SQL: Unable to use 'with as' to save selected result

Tags: sql

I have an inner join result that I want to save it by using `with as` but received an error. I'm using snowflake.

My code:

```
with t as (select *
from
(select ID, PRICE from DB.TABLE1 
WHERE PRICE IS NOT NULL and ID = '1111') A
inner join 
(select ID, BID, ACCEPTED from DB.TABLE2
WHERE BID IS NOT NULL and ID = '1111') B
ON A.ID = B.ID);
```

Error: `SQL compilation error: syntax error line 8 at position 25 unexpected ';'.`

If I only run the inner join

```
select *
    from
    (select ID, PRICE from DB.TABLE1 
    WHERE PRICE IS NOT NULL and ID = '1111') A
    inner join 
    (select ID, BID, ACCEPTED from DB.TABLE2
    WHERE BID IS NOT NULL and ID = '1111') B
    ON A.ID = B.ID
```

I got this result

```
ID,  PRICE,ID,BIDS,ACCEPTED
1111,180,1111,200,FALSE
1111,180,1111,180,FALSE
1111,180,1111,180,FALSE
1111,180,1111,100,TRUE
```

Any idea why I got the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `with` to essentially create an alias (called a common table expression) for the query that can then be used in that specific query. All you've done is create the alias without using it. You need something like:

```
with t as (select *
    from
    (select ID, PRICE from DB.TABLE1 
    WHERE PRICE IS NOT NULL and ID = '1111') A
    inner join 
    (select ID, BID, ACCEPTED from DB.TABLE2
    WHERE BID IS NOT NULL and ID = '1111') B
    ON A.ID = B.ID)
select * from t
```

Although obviously you'd usually do more complex work than that or else you'd just write the base query without using `with`

Answer (score 1):

`WITH` is syntax used to introduced a *common table expression*. This is an expression used within a *single* query. It is a lot like a subquery in the `FROM` clause, except that it can be referenced more than once.

So a correct usage would be:

```
with t as (
      select . . .
     )
select count(*)
from t;
```

In other words, you need to follow the `with` with something that uses the CTE. Otherwise, you want to store the results in a real table -- temporary or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

To use CTE, join should be made after creating the tables.

```
with t as 
(select ID, PRICE from DB.TABLE1 
WHERE PRICE IS NOT NULL and ID = '1111') ,
t1 as 
(select ID, BID, ACCEPTED from DB.TABLE2
 WHERE BID IS NOT NULL and ID = '1111') 
select * 
from t
inner join
t1
on t.ID = t1.ID;
```

Comment: "To use CTE, join should be made after creating the tables." This statement is not [true](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gE7KWJxwwfqytnzGYoguF4/0), this linked website allows to change between three SQL database systems, MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite all three worked like **expected** with a JOIN in the CTE.